# Facebook oauth auth_type=reauthenticate not working for certain users

Tags: facebook, oauth

My app requests authentication from Facebook.  We discovered a problem if the user was already logged into Facebook and the user that they were logged into Facebook as had already authorized the app.  Facebook would authenticate the app using who you are logged in without telling the user who they are authenticating.  We have users with multiple Facebook accounts and this was causing a problem because people were authenticating the wrong account without realizing it.  I fixed that problem by adding the auth_type=reauthenticate to the query string.

According to Facebook the auth_type=reauthenticate parameter will always require the user to enter their password again: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reauthentication/

Unfortunately, the auth_type=reauthenticate parameter isn't working for certain accounts.  Most users will be prompted for a password, but some users will just get passed through if they have already authorized the app.  There doesn't seem to be a reason why the auth_type=reauthenticate parameter works for some users, but is ignored for other users.  The users who ignore that value do it all the time.

The authorization URL I am using is this:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[my_client_id]&redirect_uri=[my_redirect_uri]&display=popup&auth_type=reauthenticate&response_type=code%20token&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages,offline_access

(With [my_client_id] and [my_redirect_uri] replaced with my values)

Is there any way to get ALL users to enter their password again or is there some other way to get Facebook to show the user what account they are authenticating?